# ionic2 local storage get

Tags: angular, ionic2, local-storage

I just started to use ionic2, where in my app I ask the user to store an apiKey and secret.

When storing in local storage it works fine, but I am getting trouble when try to use stored value.

```
// Storing user apikey config
saveAPISettings(apiConfig) {
  let apiSettings = { apiKey: apiConfig.apiKey, apiKeySecret: apiConfig.apiKeySecret};
  this.storage.set('api-settings', JSON.stringify(apiSettings));
}

// Stored value
"api-settings": "{"apiKey":"2b749127b41927b491274b924927b412","apiKeySecret":"QEWIRP"}" 


// Getting stored apikey config
getSettings(key) {
  let results = [];
  let object;

  this.storage.get(key).then((val) => {
    object = JSON.parse(val);
    results['apiKey'] = object.apiKey;
    results['apiKeySecret'] = object.apiKeySecret;
  });
  return results;
}
```

[image]

```
 // getSettings usage
 let config = getSettings('api-settings');

 // getting undefined
 console.log(config.apiKey);
 or 
 console.log(config['apiKey']);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to stringify your object apiSettings  just save as object

```
this.storage.set('api-settings', apiSettings);
```

Storage.get will resolve a promise just return the storage  in getSettings

```
getSettings(key) {
  return this.storage.get(key)
}
```

In your settings page

```
 getSettings('api-settings').then(val=>{
   console.log(val.apiKey);
   console.log(val.apiKeySecret);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried out. But getting undefined on both console.logs.

Comment: My bad, its working I forgot to updated the apikey.
Thanks man, you saves the day :)